# Floating <button> objects

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to float a `<div>` containing `<button>` objects right (`float: right;`),
but when the objects are floated they become unclickable?

If I `text-align: right;` then the buttons are clickable, but it pushes the left side objects down a line.

Is this a bug, and how can I work around it?

This happens in the latest versions of both Firefox and Chrome.

**Edit:**
I've found that the main "body" of the button is unclickable, but the top 1 pixel edge is clickable (firefox).

CSS for the DIV;

```
#cmd-bar {
    float: right;
}
```

HTML markup for the DIV;

```
<div id="cmd-bar">
    Select a command: 
    <button onClick="RunTask('start');">Start</button>
    <button onClick="RunTask('end');">Stop</button>
    <button onClick="RunTask('reset');">Reset</button>
    <!--<progress id="progressbar" value="50" max="100"></progress> -->
</div>
```

The buttons are always wrapped, and it's only when I apply a float to them, that the clicking of them becomes an issue.

Comment: It sounds like that div is wrapping the button and as a result you are not able to click. Share your code to let you know exactly the issue

Comment: As you can see it works http://jsfiddle.net/D37S8/ So it is caused by something else from your code.

Comment: Edited to include sample source.

Comment: Are you doing it in jsfiddle?

Comment: Still works :http://jsfiddle.net/D37S8/1/ It is not caused by the code you posted. It is something else. Post all code.

Comment: Added direct link to the page;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/23kNk/1/ - this works :) The jsfiddle [ result ] "placeholder" made button uclickable but giving a margin up or right helped me :)  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `img` that is positioned right above the buttons.

Add:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
```

to `#cmd-bar`.

This will position the buttons above the image that is currently above it.

Answer (score 0):

The div "#status-img" make it unclickable :)
It's above your buttons!

Add a

```
#status-img {
   margin-right: 500px;
}
```